# Defining custom exception in a module in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, module

I've created a custom module (which currently only defines a new Exception class), and put it under `lib/lib_th.rb`

```
module LibTH
    module Error
        IDNotFound = Class.new
    end
end
```

I should not need to require/include the module in my code, as it should be automatically loaded, since it follows the conventional naming rules.

But when i try and raise the `IDNotFound` exception somewhere in my code:

```
res.size == 0 ? raise LibTH::Error::IDNotFound : res
```

I get the follwoing error:

```
SyntaxError (/Users/lrnz/code/ruby/corinna/app/models/treasure_hunt.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
  res.size == 0 ? raise LibTH::Error::IDNotFound : res
                             ^
/Users/lrnz/code/ruby/corinna/app/models/treasure_hunt.rb:49: syntax error, unexpected ':'
  res.size == 0 ? raise LibTH::Error::IDNotFound : res
                                                  ^):
app/controllers/treasure_hunts_controller.rb:50:in `show'
```

The strange thing is that I encounter no problems trying to raise the exception in `script/console`:

```
>> raise LibTH::Error::IDNotFound
LibTH::Error::IDNotFound: LibTH::Error::IDNotFound
from (irb):70
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, i solved the problem myself:

instead of using the `if ? then : else` statement, i expanded it into a:

```
raise LibTH::Error::IDNotFound if res.size == 0
res
```

It seems you can't use a constant value (as a class name) in the C-like `if` statement, thus the:

```
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting kDO or '{' or '('
```

Thanks asy!

Answer (score 2):

The constant isn't a problem, you just have a syntax error with the raise. If you changed it to:

```
res.size == 0 ? (raise LibTH::Error::IDNotFound) : res
```

It would work. The form you corrected to is better anyway, though.